# Exception when calling MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256")

Tags: java, cryptography, sha256

I have code that works well on Android. When I ported it to my Windows 64-bit machine with JRE 1.6, the code did not work.

When I run the following line of code:

```
final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256")
```

I get the following exception:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256 MessageDigest not available  at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(Unknown Source)

I found on Internet people claiming that it is possible to use SHA256 with the standard crypto provider that comes with Sun JRE and people saying that I need to use another provider like for example Bouncy Castle.

I would prefer not to use a different provider. Is it possible to make it working?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When in doubt over what algorithms you can use for a JCA service, your first port of call should be the JCA [Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html).  The algorithms **guaranteed** to be supported by the [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest) service in a JCA-compliant JVM are:

- `MD2`
- `MD5`
- `SHA-1`
- `SHA-256`
- `SHA-384`
- `SHA-512`

It's common for providers to supply aliases for these algorithms, which is why it'd probably work with Bouncy Castle, but you should stick to these if you can to maximise portability.

If you change your code to the following, it will work as expected:

```
final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
```

Comment: Yes, `"SHA256"` is an alias present in Bouncy. I had a Bouncy Castle bug fixed that used `"SHA256"` in one of the protocol packages of Bouncy, instead of `"SHA-256"` which has been the standard name in the JCE. This is the danger of accepting more than the absolute minimum - it works one way but not the other.

Comment: So, uh, what do you do when the "guaranteed" MD5 fails.  In the Oracle JRE, but only on some machines and not others...  That's got me stumped right now.  :-(

Comment: Have you checked your security providers?

Comment: Make sure to get the right list for your JVM version, java 8 contains more algorithms than 6.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch - MD5 is not FIPS-140-2 compliant and is often blocked. Best practice is to use a SHA-2 hash instead (so SHA-256, SHA-385, SHA-512 or better)  - even if you aren't working with a crypto secret, such as a message digest. This is a huge problem in the C/C++ ecosystem when the kernel is placed in FIPS mode.

Answer (score 4):

SHA-256 should be the parameter to getInstance()

[Link for the list of algorithms supported for message digest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA)

Comment: Thank-you. You arrived one min after David Grant though

Comment: The link is broken.