# Why do I'm getting error: NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown?

Tags: java

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashBytes = md.digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(byte b : hashBytes){
            sb.append(String.format("%02x",b));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print the SHA-256 encryption value of a string but while compiling this error is showing:

```
error: unreported exception NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                                                    ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception when calling MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642742/exception-when-calling-messagedigest-getinstancesha256)

Comment: The instantiation is dynamic, in some places one must download stronger algorithms because of export limitations in the US. Then suddenly 1024 bits is not allowed for the desire algorithm or the existing JRE at the user site has SHA-256 not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have it surrounded by try-catches

```
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong");
    }
```

Comment: I would wrap the exception in catch block into RuntimeException(e)  as things can go wrong with 'md'  variable and to inform the programmer that he made mistake or typo instead of writing that into console.

Answer (score 2):

Just sorround your code with try catch like following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
public class Solution {
    try
      {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
         String s = sc.nextLine();
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-256" );
         byte[] hashBytes = md.digest( s.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) );
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for ( byte b : hashBytes )
         {
            sb.append( String.format( "%02x", b ) );
         }
         System.out.println( sb.toString() );
      }
      catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Or add throw declaration like

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{}
```